# How to stagger loop every 10 minutes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Summary of Issue**

I have a command that I run every hour. It loops over and array of 6 items and posts data to twitter. The issue is that it posts all 6 items to twitter at once. I'd like for each element of the loop to be staggered every 10 minutes. This way the twitter followers do not get spammed with tweets from us every hour.

**What I've Tried**

I did do a not so elegant solution to this. Simply adding `sleep(600);` to the loop.

```
foreach ($parks as $park) {
    Twitter::post(...);
    sleep(600);
}
```

This works fine, but I feel like there is a better way than having this process live for an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Job and queued it with a delay. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Park;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class PostToTwitter implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
    * The tweet
    *
    * @var App\Park
    */
    public $park;

    /**
    * Create a new job instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct(Park $park)
    {
        $this->park = $park;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the job.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {
        // handles posting to twitter
    }
}
```

... and then to queue those.

```
foreach ($parks as $key => $park) {
    $job = (new PostToTwitter($park))
        ->delay(now()->addMinutes($key * 10));

    dispatch($job);
}
```

Each job would be delayed by 10 minutes, in this case.

Comment: So the job would just handle the twitter post and I just pass in the park information? `Twitter::post(...);` That way each twitter post is delayed?

Comment: Yes. The delay is set to 1 minute in my particular case, but you can change that. Please keep in mind that Queues like SQS has a maximum delay of 15 mins.

Comment: You probably meant `delay(now()->addMinutes($key * 10))`, but good example.

Comment: I like the jobs idea because I can implement it in what I already have and it doesn't keep a process open. Thanks!

Comment: @Namoshek Not really. Why `* 10`?

Comment: @Mozammil in my question I mentioned that I wanted it to be staggered every 10 minutes.

Comment: @Mozammil Because he wants his six posts to be spread accross the full hour. He doesn't want them to be posted within five minutes. :)

Comment: Also, your `__construct` seems wrong, Shouldn't it be `__construct(Park $park)`?

Comment: Yes @fyroc, I guess he didn't really know what your model is called. Your code doesn't show it.

Comment: In the loop he is passing in `$park`, so I assumed he had an idea. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. I just made an assumption to explain the logic. That you'd pass in a Tweet that needs to handled. Edited the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a queue system in place, I'd recommend using [delayed dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#delayed-dispatching) instead of a cronjob. You could also have a scheduled cronjob once an hour that dispatches six of these scheduled queue jobs.

If you prefer using your current system, you can use `date('i')` to get the current hours minutes. You can then divide the minutes by 10 and round the result to the floor. It will leave you with an index for your array between 0 and 5:

```
$minutes = (int) date('i');
$index = floor($minutes / 10);

$park = $parks[$index];
```

With this logic in place, you can simply schedule your current job to run every ten minutes instead of every hour.

*Note: You might want to check if `$index` is within the range of your array, just to be on the safe side.*